# nginx does not work with simple configuration

Tags: nginx

I have the next configuration of nginx:

```
root@ubuntu:/# vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        server {
          location / {
            root /var/web/Project;
          }
        }
        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
```

In the **/var/web/Project** I have **index.html** file. Server has **192.168.136.129** address. But when I go to **http://192.168.136.129/index.html** or **http://192.168.136.129** default nginx page is loaded.
What I have done wrong? Restarting nginx does not help(((

Comment: You need to explicitly tell Nginx what port to listen to. Otherwise it will listen to none. Put "listen 192.168.136.129:80;" into your server block. Also, if you can see the standard Nginx welcome page, then there is the default server defined somewhere. It might be included from conf.d with "include" directive in the bottom of the configuration file. Try to find and comment this include.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart your nginx service?

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: >>Restarting nginx does not help((( Sure

Comment: @ovod In my opinion, this config should work. Did you clear the browser cache (or just try to open this website in incognito mode)?